# Using JS to add more input

Tags: javascript, html, input

I'm trying to add more inputs using a button using JS and can't figure it out.

So, I have this code in my HTML:

```
 <div id="ingredients" class="ingredients">
      <h2 class="tk-freight-sans-pro">Ingredients</h2>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Ingredient">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Ingredient">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Ingredient">
      <br>
      <button class="button" onclick="addIngredient();">Add Ingredient</button>
    </div>
```

And my JS is here:

```
function addIngredient() {
        var list = document.getElementById("ingredients")
        list.innerHTML += "<input type="text" placeholder="Ingredient">"
     }
```

Does anyone know what's going on or what I need to do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```js
list.innerHTML += "<input type="text" placeholder="Ingredient">"
```

should be like that:

```js
list.innerHTML += "<input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Ingredient\">"
```

or like that:

```js
list.innerHTML += '<input type="text" placeholder="Ingredient">'
```

You can't use a double quote in a string wrapped by double quotes. You have to escape the quotes in the string or use simple quotes to wrap it.

Also you should put a `;` after each instruction.

Comment: @tns12 - You should accept this answer as correct :) (assuming it solved the problem you asked about, which it should)